# Sumar valores de un array

Tags: php

Estoy sacando los datos de un CSV en el cual tengo 1 columna con input, y necesito que al darle al botón calcular me sume todos los campos de la columna y me muestre el total de ellos. Os dejo una captura ya que creo que ayudará más. Los inputs tendría que rellenarlos con números

```
   <?php
    echo '<html><body>';
    echo '<form method="POST">';
    $row = 0;
    if (($handle = fopen('nota.csv', 'r')) !== FALSE) {

    echo '<table>';

    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ',')) !== FALSE) {
    echo '<tr>';
    $row++;

    echo '<td>' . $data[0] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $data[1] . '</td>'; 

    if (strlen($data[2]) < 5 && $data[2] <= 3) {
    echo '<td><input type="text" value="' . $data[2] . '" name="value' . $row . '" /></td>';
    } else {
    echo '<td>' . $data[2] . '</td>';
    }

    echo '<td>' . $data[3] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $data[4] . '</td>';

    echo '</tr>';
    }

    fclose($handle);

    echo '</table>';
    }

    echo '<button class="btn btn-primary" name="calculate">Calcular</button>';
    echo '</form>';
    echo '</body></html>';


    if (isset($_POST['calculate'])) {
    for ($n = 2; $n < 17; $n++) {
    $valores = $_POST['value' . $n];
    }
    }

    ?>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Si los datos ya están en cada columna, puedes usar `array_sum`, como bien dice @DavidJP en su respuesta, prescindiendo de un botón `Calcular`, pues ya conoces los datos de antemano. Si el escenario es diferente, por ejemplo, que el usuario pueda cambiar cualquiera de los valores una vez cargados, entonces la suma tendría que hacerse del lado del cliente, usado Javascript, escuchando los clicks del botón calcular. En ese caso lo más simple sería asignar una clase a todos los `input` que contienen números.

Answer (score 0):

La instrucción de php para sumar los elementos de un array es `array_sum` que, aplicada a tu caso, sería:

```
$total=array_sum($data);
```

Para crear varios `input` con diferentes values, mejor utiliza:

```
name="valor[]"
```

De esta forma podrás recoger los datos en el array `$_POST['valor']` sin necesidad de tener que formar el nombre de cada variable con un for, como haces el final.

Y ya, en general, permíteme hacerte un par de recomendaciones:

- Tabula el código, pues indentado resulta mucho más fácil de leer y entender qué intentas hacer
- Intenta extraer de tu código un [Ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) que podamos ejecutar, por ejemplo, sin tener tu fichero .csv. De esta forma podremos darte una solución que hayamos comprobado que funciona (y no trozos de código sueltos que son más recomendaciones que soluciones) y, además, cualquiera puede reutilizar ese caso concreto y sencillo en situaciones similares, resultando útil para más miembros de la comunidad.

Si te surge cualquier complicación, edita tu pregunta y, con gusto, ampliaré mi respuesta